# Restore links from Windows 7 profile

Tags: windows-7, windows

They upgraded our version of Outlook and my developer PC wouldn't upgrade as it had an error, so they re-created my Windows profile.  We're on Windows 7.
Now I've lost all of my mapped drives and ODBC connections.
I suspect the links are still in my registry, but my profile has lost the connections to them.
Is there a way to restore links from my registry to my new user profile?
I think the settings I've lost were in NTUser.dat, which was a large file before and I now understand is the hive for that profile.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try this information for restoring your [ODBC connections](https://www.google.com/amp/s/kencenerelli.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/export-an-odbc-data-source-from-the-registry/amp/) and this for your [mapped drives](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0c44732e-60dd-4ddd-a19f-c5772cdfd54e/map-network-drive-registry-path?forum=w7itprovirt). Also, your question is a little bit unclear due to grammar. Can you clarify *my developer PC wouldn't had an error*?